# Маршрутизация трафика в програмах

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Добрый день.

Есть ли демон или проект маршрутизации трафика программы между компьютерами и серверами.

Поясню: 
Есть мессенджер написанный организацией. В организации несколько серверов и на каждый сервер приходится по несколько десятков машин. У каждой машины или сервера есть этот месенджер и уникальный идентификатор. На сервере хранится таблица(забитая вручную) какой идентификатор на каком ip сидит(ip статические). Получается, что если пользователь отправляет сообщение, то оно сначала идёт на сервер, а потом или на сервер или на машину. Даже если эти машины сидят на одном сервере. Получается, что если один сервер упадёт, все машины этого сервера не смогут отправлять сообщения. К тому же сервер является пробкой, если будет большой траффик.

Я пробовал построить всё на bird ospf. Т.е. router id как идентификатор, bird установлен на каждой машине и сервере, и чтобы месенджер при отправке сообщения смотрел самый быстрый и свободный канал и отправлял по нему(может быть на другую машину, а та в свою очередь получателю). Но, в таблице маршрутизации помимо router id ещё и сеть. И получается путаница идентификатора и сети.

Есть ли программа или блок кода или библиотека которая может решить этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Есть. Jabber называется. Выкидывайте ваш велосипед и переходите на него, там уже все реализовано.

Comment: Нет, тут так не получится. Потому что помимо месенджера на этой маршрутизации сидят и интернет ресурсы и хранилища

Comment: Так.. Давайте разводить проблемы по уровням модели OSI. Сейчас у вас перемешаны прикладной с канальным - на выходе - путаница.

Мессенджер, интернет, ресурсы и хранилища - это одно приложение или разные?

Comment: Это разные, но одно завязано на другое. К примеру: пользователь отправляет сообщение по месенджеру. Месенжер локально обращается к транспортной задаче. Та, в свою очередь просматривает таблицу уникального идентификатора(если есть) и берёт ip адрес следующего узла. Если нет, то отправляет свой сервер. Следующий узел или сервер так же просматривает свою таблицу и передаёт.
По такому принципу работает и хранилище и интернет ресурсы.

Comment: @kostap жуть какая, а разработчики и архитекторы этого шоу доступны? 
Давайте теперь ставить задачу - вы хотите автоматом получать на серверах файл сотоветствий id-ip?

Comment: согласен, жуть тут есть. Но система очень старая и поэтому простительно. Для начала хотелось бы получать оптимальный маршрут для каждого узла, если узел находится в одной автономной системе(т.е. на одном сервере) и на серверах об всех остальных серверах + всю свою автономную систему. Я думаю, что это хорошее решение. Оно позволит при подключении новой автономной области не прописывать её на каждом сервере а автоматически. Так же при отправке данных выбирался оптимальный маршрут. 
Следующей задачей думаю делать транспортную задачу, которая бы создавала тунель до аббонента.

Comment: @kostap а как абоненты узнают сервер, к которому цепляться? Это все на форточке работает?

Comment: у аббонента прописан сервер, к которому он подключается. Что значит "работает на форточке"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42422/discussion-between-kostap-and-gbg).